# Register mouse data sequences in pseudoterminal with conpty

Tags: node.js, terminal, console, console-application, pty

I'm working on a terminal emulator written in js, built on top of **node-pty** and now I'm testing on windows. I'm currently stuck on trying to send mouse control sequences to the terminal, which I test on MidnightCommander ran in powershell.
Here's my pty constructor:

```
var ptyProcess = pty.spawn('powershell.exe', [], {
name: 'ms-terminal',
cols: 120,
rows: 40,
cwd: "E:/cwd",
env: process.env,
useConpty: true
});
```

I tried to send the mouse click event sequence in this format `\x1b[<0;x;yM"`, but that doesn't seem to do anything. Until I switch and stop using conpty: `useConpty: false` then this sequence works perfectly. But obviously I want to keep using conpty with my application. I also tried to start the session with sequences to enable mouse event reporting: `ptyProcess.write("\x1b[?1003h\x1b[?1015h\x1b[?1002h\x1b[?1006h")`, but this also didn't help.
Am I using wrong kind of sequences that are not compatible with conpty? What should I do to be able to send mouse data to terminal with conpty and are there any ways to test it other than using midnight commander?

Comment: For testing, you can use other terminal applications that support mouse events like Vim, tmux, neovim, or any other similar applications.

Comment: This [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/) indicates that conpty is more/less used to provide something like ConsoleAPI (not escape sequences).  So you'll have to live with ms-terminal's limitations.